# PHP: Include file from different root directory

Tags: php

I have 2 root directories for a site, httpdocs and httpsdocs. I am sure its obvious what the 2 are for. But I want to keep things consistent through-out the site like global navigation. Right now I have two separate files for this (one in each side) and I would like to only have one. This is hard to maintain because each time I change one I have to change the other (if I remember to), it breaks the DRY rule. But if I try to include a file from one side to the other using a relative path it tells me the file path is not allowed because it goes outside the document root. If I try to include it with an absolute URL I get another error saying file access is disabled in the server configuration. (I am on a hosting account so the most I can change as far as server config is limited to .htaccess). So can anyone think of a work-around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put your global include file in yet another directory (lets call it `library`) and then have each http root have an include file that includes `../library/lib.php`, then sets specific paramaters.  This gives you the added benifit of your library php files not being in the document root path as well.

And actually.  Updating because I just read the entry about "relative path" issues.

Could you set the "include path" php value to include that directory?

Something like this:

```
ini_set('include_path', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."/../library").":".ini_get('include_path'));
require_once('lib.php');
```

Did a little more research - seems that changing `open_basedir` is not possible unless you are able to edit the httpd.conf or php.ini values.  [PHP Manual: open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.open-basedir)

Comment: If they are not in the document root I cannot access them, I get an error telling me the path is not allowed every time I try. Is there a way to ALLOW this using .htaccess or something?

Comment: I get this error when I try what you said: 
Warning: main(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/library/lib.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpsdocs:/tmp)

:(

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to complain to your hosting provider that /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com should be your "allowed path" not just httpsdocs or httpdocs.  You may be able to override it with php_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com:/tmp" in your .htaccess  - if that doesn't fix your problem - complain to your host

Comment: @gnarf, thanks what exactly should I put in my .htaccess file? this line exactly: [php_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com:/tmp"]? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I would hope that would work (updated the answer to include that option as well) - but if not - its just bad configuration of the hosting provider.  Its foolish to put "library" files in your document root anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I added that to my .htaccess on both sides and didn't see a change. I sent my hosting provider an email, hopefully they'll fix it. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I'm going to guess you're using Plesk - you should put the openbasedir directive in your vhost.conf, in the conf folder above httpdocs.

<Directory /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs>
        php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/dir/you/need/access/too:/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs:/tmp"
</Directory>

Comment: @Hieronymus, YES I am using Plesk, when I FTP into the server I can see the conf directory but I don't have permission to open it. My hosting provider said all they can do is point both http and https to the httpdocs directory, which would take a lot of work on my end to make sure it went smoothly because it is a very large site with many files on the httpsdocs side.

Comment: Either your hosting company or the administrator of this server need to give you permissions to modify vhost.conf. I'm the admin on my server, so I just ssh in and do what I need to. Alternatively you could ask them to place the correct directive in vhost.conf for you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the ability to create [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_(Unix)) between the two directories?

Comment: I am not sure, my hosting is LAMP, how would I go about creating one? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think I can, I looked it up and I guess I need terminal access to the server but I do not, I can ask my service provider to set it up, is it possible to make a symbolic link to a directory then any file I want to share put in that directory? Thanks

Comment: I also tried to create one using PHP's symlink() and I get an error saying: "Permission denied". Very frustrating.